# How to get gps location with Network MOBILE and not Network Wi-Fi

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location, coordinates

Is it possible to get the coordinates only with the mobile network enabled?
I need to get the coordinates within 30 seconds. Because when the user clicks the button to hide, it can not be too long to get the coordinates.
I can not use NETWORK_PROVIDER to get the coordinates of the Wi-Fi network because the user will be on the street and not connected to a Wi-Fi network, but will have the mobile data network connected.
Is it possible to get coordinates over the mobile data network?
I know GPS_PROVIDER is slower than NETWORK_PROVIDER, so I'd like to know if it's possible as I said above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the coordinates only with the mobile network enabled?

Yes. For example, navigation apps work while driving in open spaces, far from any WiFi.

> I need to get the coordinates within 30 seconds

There is no way to guarantee this. There is no way to guarantee that you can get a GPS fix in any amount of time. There are plenty of places in the world where it is difficult to get GPS signals.

Comment: Exactly. Only I have not been able to do that. When I leave only the mobile data network enabled, the coordinates are not captured. If not ask too much, would you have an example of this case?

Comment: @WilkeGutierre: There is nothing special that you need to do. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Location/Classic) demonstrates getting a location fix. I tried it on a Nexus 5X with WiFi disabled. My weather forecast popped up after several seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reference you gave me, you'll help me with this.
In fact, the weather is not very well the problem. My biggest problem is that I can not get coordinates with only the mobile data network enabled. Is the permission to get through it the same for Wi-Fi (NETWORK_PROVIDER)?

Comment: @WilkeGutierre: "the weather is not very well the problem" -- the sample app uses `LocationManager` and `GPS_PROVIDER` to get a location fix. Then, it uses the US National Weather Service to get a weather forecast. "Is the permission to get through it the same for Wi-Fi (NETWORK_PROVIDER)?" -- if you want to use `GPS_PROVIDER`, you need the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, including requesting the permission at runtime. All of this is illustrated in the sample app (and described in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android)).

Comment: :Thank you very much for your attention. I will analyze the project that is very useful for me. Anyway, you want it as an answer, because I really help answer my problem. Thank you!